# Как узнать установленную версию OpenGL в линуксе?

Tags: linux, opengl

Как узнать установленную версию OpenGL в линуксе ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в терминале надо в вести

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

**Вывод:**

```
????@astra:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GL [Quadro K600] (rev a1)
????@astra:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: NVE7
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 18.1.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
????@astra:~$
```

*у меня версия опенгл
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.1.3*